# QML: object instantiation

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, object-construction

Is there a way to have a mechanism similar to [Component.createObject's](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#createObject-method) second argument (initial properties) with a `Loader` element? I'm setting the properties manually in `onLoaded`, but this has slightly different semantics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`setSource()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#setSource-method):

```
// example.qml
import QtQuick 2.0
Item {
    Loader {
        id: squareLoader
        onLoaded: console.log(squareLoader.item.width);
        // prints [10], not [30]
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        squareLoader.setSource("ExampleComponent.qml",
                             { "color": "blue" });
        // will trigger the onLoaded code when complete.
    }
}
```